# Printing Adorner Layers in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, adorner, adornerlayer

I have a `richTextBox` Editor that contains image `adorner` layers on top of each word.

I want to print the document in a good format and print the `adorner` picture layers too.

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

 I tried `PrintDialog` but it didnt print the adorner layers.

Comment: Not really a direct answer, but can this link help you?http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ae8312df-9ed9-4c4c-951b-42cee5427afa/
You could print as an XPS the whole content control, and then you should have the adorners with it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to print an Adorner layer associated with a  item using http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ae8312df-9ed9-4c4c-951b-42cee5427afa/ . I don't know if it would work for the RichTextBox, I wasn't able to add the Adorner inside the RichTextBox.

Since the Adorner is added OnRender, I had to wait until all was rendered on screen before printing it (hence the Print button), if I printed in the Window_Loaded function, I did not get the Adorner layer.

The Style to the ContentControl is necessary for the AdornerLayer to print.

Code follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <AdornerDecorator>
          <ContentPresenter
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
        </AdornerDecorator>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentControl Name="MyContent">
    <StackPanel>
<Grid Name="MyGrid" Margin="10">
    <RichTextBox Name="MyDoc" Margin="2">
        <FlowDocument Name="MyFlow">
            <Paragraph Name="MyParagraph">
                I am a flow document. Would you like to edit me?
                    <Bold>Go ahead.</Bold>
            </Paragraph>

            <Paragraph Foreground="Blue">
                I am blue I am blue I am blue.
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Print</Button>
        </StackPanel>
</ContentControl>
```

Window code

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myAdornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(MyDoc);
        myAdornerLayer.Add(new SimpleCircleAdorner(MyDoc));


    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LocalPrintServer ps = new LocalPrintServer();
        PrintQueue pq = ps.DefaultPrintQueue;
        XpsDocumentWriter xpsdw = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(pq);
        PrintTicket pt = pq.UserPrintTicket;
        if (xpsdw != null)
        {
            pt.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
            PageMediaSize pageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight);
            pt.PageMediaSize = pageMediaSize;

            xpsdw.Write(MyContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Adorner from Microsoft [SimpleCircleAdorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746703%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This works great, but it only prints the content of the document which is visible on the screen, not the content of the whole document :(

Comment: I think that since the Adorners are added "On Render", probably won't be able to print those "off-sceen".
Maybe the best way is to create a real XPS document where you prepare everything for printing and add the Adorners as real images embedded in the document. I don't have a better suggestion for the moment, good luck.

Comment: How can I do that? I tried alot of things already, and nothing is giving me a good result.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative I used when I had to create a report, was I used a [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx) into which I embedded everything I needed. You can see what that looks like [here](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/7122/reportis.jpg).

Here is the ugly code used to generate this report, I hope this might help and give you pointers on what to do if you go this way. Apologies if it's too long, I don't have the time to clean it up, start reading at "//START of FlowDocument".

For including UI elements into the report, you can use UIContainers as described under the FlowDocument link. And maybe mix it with the solution created [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432395/create-custom-frameworkcontentelement-to-add-diagonal-line-over-text-in-wpf) to add Adorners to a flow document?

```
    private FlowDocument HydroPowerReportI(string PlantPath, string PlantName, bool filled)
    {
        //Ignore these first 20 lines, they are there to populate my data
        List<HydroMarket.LocalData.BinaryIO.HydroFileIO.Report1> data = new List<HydroMarket.LocalData.BinaryIO.HydroFileIO.Report1>();
        int nTime = 0;
        List<int> iReportingPoints = new List<int>();
        SimulationsTreeViewModel S = (this.DataContext as SimulationsTreeViewModel);
        List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
        if (filled)
        {
            if (HydroFileIO.ObtainReportI(data, out nTime, PlantPath))
            {
                MarketParameters m = MarketParameters.ReadScenarioParameters(new FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(PlantPath, "MarketParam.bin")));
                iReportingPoints.Add(0); 
                iReportingPoints.Add(1); 
                iReportingPoints.Add(2); 
                iReportingPoints.Add(3);
                iReportingPoints.Add(4);

                dates.Add(m.ValueDate);
                foreach (DateTime x in m.ReportingDates)
                {
                    DateTime dt = SetBetween(m.ValueDate, x, m.Maturity);
                    dates.Add(dt);
                }
                dates.Add(m.Maturity);
            }
            else
            {
                filled = false;
            }
        }
        //START of FlowDocument 
        Brush HeaderColor = Brushes.RoyalBlue;
        FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument();

        //Original table holder with columns
        Table table2 = new Table();
        flowDoc.Blocks.Add(table2);

        table2.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
        table2.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
        table2.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
        table2.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
        table2.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
        table2.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());

        table2.Columns[0].Width = new GridLength(280);

        // Create and add an empty TableRowGroup to hold the table's Rows.
        table2.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());
        // Add the first (title) row.
        table2.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
        // Alias the current working row for easy reference.
        TableRow currentRow2 = new TableRow();
        currentRow2 = table2.RowGroups[0].Rows[0];

        // Add cells with content to the second row.
        currentRow2.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Valuation Report"))));
        currentRow2.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 6; //1 less than center for offsetting it
        currentRow2.FontSize = 32;
        currentRow2.Foreground = HeaderColor;
        currentRow2.Cells[0].TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;

        table2.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
        currentRow2 = table2.RowGroups[0].Rows[1];
        if (filled)
            if (S.SimSetup.LastSimulation.HasValue)
                currentRow2.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Valuation: " + S.Name + "\nMarket: " + S.SimSetup.Market.Name + "\nPlant: " + PlantName + "\nLast simulated at: " + S.SimSetup.LastSimulation.Value.ToLongDateString() + " " + S.SimSetup.LastSimulation.Value.ToShortTimeString()))));
            else
                currentRow2.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Valuation: " + S.Name + "\nMarket: " + S.SimSetup.Market.Name + "\nPlant: " + PlantName))));
        else
        {
            //BUGFIX: 091113 
            //When no data is loaded, it is unclear that it has not loaded data
            currentRow2.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("No simulation data available for valuation " + S.Name))));
        }
        currentRow2.Cells[0].TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        currentRow2.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 6; //all for the center
        currentRow2.Cells[0].Padding = new Thickness(10);

        //Table Headers
        // Create and add an empty TableRowGroup to hold the table//s Rows.
        table2.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());
        // Add the first (title) row.
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
        // Alias the current working row for easy reference.
        int iRow = 0;
        TableRow currentRow = new TableRow();
        currentRow = table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[iRow];
        // Add the header row with content,
        if (filled)
        {
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(" "))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Value date"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(" "))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(" "))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(" "))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Maturity"))));

            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            iRow = 1;
            currentRow = table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[iRow];
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(" "))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(dates[0].ToShortDateString()))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(dates[1].ToShortDateString()))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(dates[2].ToShortDateString()))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(dates[3].ToShortDateString()))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(dates[4].ToShortDateString()))));
        }
        else
        {
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(" "))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Value date"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(""))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(""))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(""))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Maturity"))));
            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            iRow = 1;
            currentRow = table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[iRow];
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(" "))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(" "))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(" "))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(" "))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(" "))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(" "))));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            currentRow.Cells[i].Foreground = HeaderColor;
            currentRow.Cells[i].TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
        }
        iRow++;
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
        currentRow = table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[iRow];
        currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        currentRow.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 6;
        currentRow.Cells[0].BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0);
        currentRow.Cells[0].BorderBrush = HeaderColor;

        for (int i = 3; i < 23; i++)
        {
            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            currentRow = table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[i];
        }
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[3].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Expected value"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[4].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Expected price"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[5].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Expected income (cumulated)"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[6].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Expected income"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[7].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Expected income by generation"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[8].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Expected costs of pumping"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[9].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Expected penalties"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[10].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Expected costs of switching on/off"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[11].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Standard deviation of value"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[12].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Value at Risk (95%)"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[13].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Generated electricity (MWh)"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[14].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Consumed electricity (MWh)"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[15].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Days generated"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[16].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Days pumped"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[17].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Expected volume (m³)"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[18].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Expected volume used for generation (m³)"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[19].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Expected volume used for pumping (m³)"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[20].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Expected volume natural inflow (m³)"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[21].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Standard deviation of volume"))));
        table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[22].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Volume at risk"))));

        if (filled)
        {
            //Writing 
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[3].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].Value.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[4].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].Price.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[5].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].IncomeCum.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[6].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].Income.ToString("N0")))));
                //table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[6].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(income[j].ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[7].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].IncomeGen.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[8].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].CostsPmp.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[9].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].Penalties.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[10].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].CostSwitch.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[11].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].StdValue.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[12].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].VaRValue.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[13].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].PowGen.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[14].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].PowPump.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[15].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].DaysGen.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[16].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].DaysPmp.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[17].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].Volume.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[18].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].VolGen.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[19].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].VolPmp.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[20].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].VolNat.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[21].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].StdVolume.ToString("N0")))));
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[22].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data[iReportingPoints[j]].VaRVolume.ToString("N0")))));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            double d = 0.00;
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 3; k < 23; k++)
                    table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[k].Cells.Add((new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(d.ToString("N0"))))));
            }
        }
        for (int r = 3; r < 23; r++)
            for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++)
                table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[r].Cells[j].TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[10].Cells[j].BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 1, 0, 0);
            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[10].Cells[j].BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[12].Cells[j].BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 1, 0, 0);
            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[12].Cells[j].BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[14].Cells[j].BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 1, 0, 0);
            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[14].Cells[j].BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[20].Cells[j].BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 1, 0, 0);
            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[20].Cells[j].BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[22].Cells[j].BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 1, 0, 0);
            table2.RowGroups[1].Rows[22].Cells[j].BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
        }

        return flowDoc;
    }
```